# Multiple tables in the where clause SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables:-

```
Table_1

GetID UnitID
1     1,2,3
2     4,5
3     5,6
4     6

Table_2

ID UnitID UserID
1  1      1
1  2      1
1  3      1
1  4      1
1  5      2
1  6      3
```

I want the **'GetID'** based on **'UserID'**.

Let me explain you with an example.
For e.g.

1. I want all the GetID where UserID is 1.
   The result set should be 1 and 2. 2 is included because one of the Units of 2 has UserID 1.
2. I want all the GetID where UserID is 2
   The result set should be 2 and 3. 2 is included because one of Units of 2 has UserID 2.

I want to achieve this.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: please show what you have tried so far

Comment: On a different note, why are you storing your data in a de-normalised format? Storing delimited lists in SQL Server is rarely a good idea.

Comment: select GetID from Table_1 AS t1
 INNER JOIN Table_2 AS t2 ON t1.LocationID = t2.LocationID AND UserID = 1
where t2.UnitID Like '%' + t1.UnitID + '%'

And many more similar queries

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want, but I understand there may be a language barrier here. One problem is you are storing UnitID as a comma separated list instead of normalizing your data. You're going to want to split those. [Here's a few methods](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a query like this:

<kbd>[See live demo](http://rextester.com/MFG71528)</kbd>

```
select 
distinct userid,getid 
from Table_1 t1 
join Table_2 t2
on t1.unitId+',' like '%' +cast(t2.unitid as varchar(max))+',%'
and t2.userid=1
```

Answer (score 1):

The query for this will be relatively ugly, because you made the mistake of storing CSV data in the `UnitID` column (or maybe someone else did and you are stuck with it).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.GetID
FROM Table_1 t1
INNER JOIN Table_2 t2
    ON ',' + t1.UnitID + ',' LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(varchar(10), t2.UnitID) + ',%'
WHERE
    t2.UserID = 1;
```

[image]

### Demo

To understand the join trick being used here, for the first row of `Table_1` we are comparing `,1,2,3,` against other single `UnitID` values from `Table_2`, e.g. `%,1,%`.  Hopefully it is clear that my logic would match a single `UnitID` value in the CSV string in any position, including the first and last.

But a much better long term approach would be to separate those CSV values across separate records.  Then, in addition to requiring a much simpler query, you could take advantage of things like indices.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    declare @Table_1 table(GetID INT, UnitId VARCHAR(10))
    declare @Table_2 table(ID INT, UnitId INT,UserId INT)



    INSERT INTO @Table_1
    SELECT 1,'1,2,3'
    union
    SELECT 2,'4,5'
    union
    SELECT 3,'5,6'
    union
    SELECT 4,'6'


    INSERT INTO @Table_2
    SELECT 1,1,1
    union
    SELECT 1,2,1
    union
    SELECT 1,3,1
    union
    SELECT 1,4,1
    union
    SELECT 1,5,2
    union
    SELECT 1,6,3


    declare @UserId INT = 2
    DECLARE @UnitId VARCHAR(10)

    SELECT @UnitId=COALESCE(@UnitId + ',', '') + CAST(UnitId AS VARCHAR(5)) from @Table_2 WHERE UserId=@UserId


    select distinct t.GetId
    from @Table_1 t
    CROSS APPLY [dbo].[Split](UnitId,',') AS AA
    CROSS APPLY [dbo].[Split](@UnitId,',') AS BB
    WHERE AA.Value=BB.Value
```

Split Function:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].Split(@input AS Varchar(4000) )

    RETURNS

          @Result TABLE(Value BIGINT)

    AS

    BEGIN

          DECLARE @str VARCHAR(20)

          DECLARE @ind Int

          IF(@input is not null)

          BEGIN

                SET @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)

                WHILE @ind > 0

                BEGIN

                      SET @str = SUBSTRING(@input,1,@ind-1)

                      SET @input = SUBSTRING(@input,@ind+1,LEN(@input)-@ind)

                      INSERT INTO @Result values (@str)

                      SET @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)

                END

                SET @str = @input

                INSERT INTO @Result values (@str)

          END

          RETURN

    END
```